# Regex Exclude Specific String

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to have a .NET regex to match `"[@foo]"` from `"applicant_data/contact_number[@foo]"` w/c I can already do using the pattern `"\[@(.*?)\]"`.

However I want to make an exception so that `"applicant_data/contact_number[@foo=2]"` does not match the pattern. So the question is what should be the regular expression so that it will get any valid alphanumeric ([@bar],[@theVar],[@zoo$6]) but not [@bar=1], [@theVar=3]?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: \[@(.*?)[^=2]\]

Comment: Is the word `foo` constant or can it vary? Also, you want to exclude it only for the number `2` or any number?

Comment: @Sefe i've tried "\[@(.*?)\]"

Comment: @Gurman foo is not fixed it can vary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
\[@[\w-]+(?!=)\]
```

the explanation:

```
"\[" &       ' Match the character “[” literally
"@" &        ' Match the character “@” literally
"[\w-]" &    ' Match a single character present in the list below
                ' A “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation)
                ' The literal character “-”
   "+" &        ' Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"(?!" &      ' Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
   "=" &        ' Match the character “=” literally
")" &
"\]"         ' Match the character “]” literally
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: any chance you could expand the answer as to only get "foo" from "@[foo]" meaning find a word character (without the "=" sign) preceded by "@[" and succeeded by "]".

Comment: i think i misunderstood your requirement... ``(?<=@\[)\w+(?=\])``...this would match word-characters surrounded by ``@[`` at start and by ``]`` at end...

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

`\[@(?![^\]]*?=).*?\]`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Gj76b/4)

**Explanation:**

- `\[@` - matches `[@` literally
- `(?![^\]]*?=)` - negative lookahead to make sure that `=` is not present anywhere before the next `]`
- `.*?` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character except a newline character
- `\]` - matches `]` literally

Comment: thanks @Gurman "=2" is not constant it could be "=bar". Frankly just detecting the presence of "=" sign inside "[@theWord]" would work.